# Isolated grounds in power supplies

Tags: power-supply, isolated

Can someone assist me with understanding why some power supplies for instance DC to DC power supplies sometimes use more than one ground in their circuit?

I have noticed that also some components on the PCB have an isolated ground. Components such as the B0505S-W2R2. Which is a 5V input, 5V output DC to DC isolated PSU.

What is the advantage of using isolated grounds in a circuit?
When do you know when to apply isolated grounds in a PCB design?

N.B.
The supplier does not provide a circuit schematic and reverse-engineering the PSU is not possible as some traces are not easily tracked since they go under some components.

Comment: Link to datasheet? Circuit schematic? Which components?

Comment: The specific converter (B0505S) you mentioned, the converter is isolated, meaning that input and output don't have a connected hard-wired part. the voltage/signal/data in these systems are transmitted over magnetic induction of said values from one circuit to another. One key advantage of it is safety.

Comment: @Transistor The supplier does not provide a circuit schematic and reverse-engineering the PSU is not possible as some traces are not easily tracked since they go under some components/ or covered.

Comment: @Transistor not all components have part numbers, I just managed to get the B0505S PSU. So I guess this is more of a question about why are isolated grounds used in circuits and when to apply them...?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reasons for using isolated power supplies (or isolated dc-dc converters) but the most common I know of is for medical devices.  Plugged-in medical devices are constraint by regulations that require isolation.  The idea is that if something would go wrong on the AC side, there can be no spillage of high voltages or currents to the DC side.  This is also why a lot of these power supplies are referred to as "medical grade".

For non-medical applications, the biggest advantage I have seen is that since the outputs are floating relative to the inputs, there is nothing to prevent you from chaining the input and output together to create higher voltages.  So if you have a 12V to 12V isolated DC-DC converter, you can connect the + of the input to the - of the output and get 24V when measured from the - of the input to the + of the output.

I have often used isolated DC-DC converters because they generally perform really well and if what I am working on is low quantity, spending the extra money is not a big deal.  In such cases, there is nothing preventing you from linking the input and output negatives and they work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to NeuroEng's comment on your question, which pretty much explains the functional part of isolated DC-DC converters, I can also give you an example from one of my old projects.

I was developing some test equipment that required positive and negative supply voltages for the intended operation of some ICs. As the external supply was a simple 230VAC to 48VDC SMPS, there were some ways to divide the 48V into three rails (+44V, 0V, and -4V). For this particular case, I was tempted to try an op-amp-based virtual ground, which is (very very basically) obtained by buffering the output of a resistor divider (provided the buffer op-amp has enough current capability).

However, during development, a few functional blocks were added and the required ICs only supported supply voltages up to 30V. The immediate solution to this problem was to incorporate a DC-DC converter, but not any converter: as the virtual ground op-amp was already sinking a great amount of current for its capabilities and the external power supply could still sink a lot more, an **isolated** DC-DC converter came in handy: at the input of the converter (Vin+ and Vin-) were the full 48V from the external supply, and at the output (Vout+ and Vout-) were the +24V rail and the virtual ground.

This way, adding to the previously mentioned electrical safety, I obtained +24V with respect to ground without loading the virtual ground op-amp.

Answer (score 0):

Every aerospace system I've worked on for over 50 years has had a requirement that the input (primary) power be isolated from the secondary voltages and returns by a minimum value of resistance, within the power supply.  This isolation requirement usually is something like 1 Mohm, but can be negotiated down to a lower value for good technical reasons.